# Upsert to a table in pyq

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, kdb, pyq

OS: `Windows 10 Enterprise`, Python: `Python 3.6.4`, PyQ: `pyq (4.1.4)`.

I'm pretty certain my data types are correct, though I keep receiving `_k.error: type` when I attempt to upsert to my table.

First I initialize the table with the following command...

```
q.set(':testTable', q('!', ["Key", "Status", "Descr", "FileName"], [K.long([]), K.int([]), K.char([]), K.symbol([])]).flip)
```

Check the table meta...

```
q.get(':testTable').meta.show()
c       | t f a
--------| -----
Key     | j
Status  | i
Descr   | c
FileName| s
```

I set some sample variables in python and store them in a list and a dictionary respectively...

```
key = 42
status = 3
descr = "h"
fn = "cymbeline"
data = [key, status, descr, fn]
data_dict = {a:b for a, b in zip(['Key', 'Status', 'Descr', 'FileName'], data)}
```

Then I try to upsert to the table, using each of the below commands separately...

```
q.upsert(':testTable', data)
q.upsert(':testTable', data_dict)
```

However, they both fail with the same `_k.error: type` message.

I assume there's a simple solution here but I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast descr to K.char type:

```
descr = K.char("h")
```

otherwise it will be implicitly converted to a symbol and you will get a type error.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. Figured it would be something simple similar to this.